# Cancel out the fraction $\frac{a^{4/3}-2a^{7/6}+a}{a^{1/3}(a^{1/3}-a^{1/2})^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Cancel out the fraction $$\dfrac{a^\frac43-2a^\frac76+a}{a^\frac13\left(a^\frac13-a^\frac12\right)^2},\qquad a>0,a\ne1.$$
The given answer is $1$. If $a^\frac12=t$ and $a^\frac13=u$, then we will have $$\dfrac{u^4-2u^2t+t^2}{u(u-t)^2}=\dfrac{(u^2-t)^2}{u(u-t)^2}$$ which isn't equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{a^\frac43-2a^\frac76+a}{a^\frac13\left(a^\frac13-a^\frac12\right)^2}$$

$$\dfrac{a^1-2a^\frac56+a^\frac23}{\left(a^\frac13-a^\frac12\right)^2}$$

$$\dfrac{\left(a^\frac13-a^\frac12\right)^2}{\left(a^\frac13-a^\frac12\right)^2}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the relation $t^2=u^3=a$ and expanding
$$\frac{(u^2-t)^2}{u(u-t)^2}=\frac{\color{blue}{t^2u}-2tu^2+t^2}{\color{blue}{t^2}-2tu^2+t^2u}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to introduce two variables, as the expressions are no more unique. Trying with $t:=a^{1/6}$,

$$\frac{a^{4/3}-2a^{7/6}+a}{a^{1/3}(a^{1/3}-a^{1/2})^2}=\frac{t^8-2t^7+t^6}{t^2(t^2-t^3)^2}=\frac{t^2-2t+1}{(1-t)^2}.$$

Comment: Yes, but how do we arrive at $t:=a^\frac16$?

Comment: @Medi: $6=\text{lcm}(2,3)$.